# Prove that Gaussian filter is linear

Tags: linear-algebra, gaussian

> Prove that the Gaussian filter: [image: Gaussian filter] is linear.

I'm not really sure how to approach this..

If I understand correctly, in order for it to be linear, we need that:

```
G(ax+z,y) = aG(x,y) + G(z,y)
```

However, I cant see how it actually stands for both additivity and homogeneity, as any of these (additivity/homogeneity) would change the exponent of the outcome only.

Comment: It's most likely that you're being asked to show the filter is linear as an operator, which is how it acts on functions of a single variable via integration: $G\cdot f \equiv \int dx G(x,y) f(x)$. And you want to show that it is linear, i.e. $G\cdot \left(f+g\right) = G\cdot f + G\cdot g$.

Answer (score 1):

This question probably needs more contextual information to be answered properly.
Since the function in the original post is a 2-dimensional Gaussian, and since it is referred to by the word "filter", I will assume the task originates from a context related to image processing, where the operation of "Gaussian filtering" essentially means "convolution with a 2D Gaussian kernel".

Under the above assumptions, it is sufficient to prove that, in general, the convolution operator is linear, i.e. $$(\alpha f+ \beta h)*g = \alpha (f*g) + \beta(h*g)$$
where $\alpha,\beta\in \mathbb{R}$ and $f,g,h:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfy the conditions for the existence of the convolution integral.
Then simply set $g=G$.